# SQL Tables - Is this design acceptable/good practice?

Tags: sql, join, relational-database

I'm in the process of developing/designing a small system to keep track of servers, what applications run on these servers, and for each application what environments exists on the server. I have a quick question about good design patterns/practices.

I have 3 tables, one for each entity. They are (abbreviated) as follows:

```
Server
Id : int

Application
Id : int

Environment
Id : int
```

Now, my question is:

Would it be acceptable to create a joining table as such:

```
AppServerEnvironments
ServerId : int
ApplicationId : int
EnvironmentId : int
```

Or, is it better practice to create two joining tables as such:

```
ApplicationServer
ServerId : int
ApplicationId : int

ApplicationEnvironment
ApplicationId : int
EnvironmentId : int
```

I've tried going with the second option, but cannot seem to figure out a way to join all 3 tables properly.

Any input/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the environment an attribute of the server?

Comment: yes - i would say ServerEnvironment instead. ApplicationEnvironemnt maybe has another meaning - like what things are required for the application to run properly. (but not necessarily what is on the machine at this point.

Comment: Each server can contain many applications. Each application can have many environments. For example, AppA can live on ServerA, ServerB, and Server C. On each Server AppA can have EnvA, EnvB, and EnvC.

Comment: the funny term here to me is Environment.  if that means OS and other supporting software, then the server has one of those, and the application 'requires' one of those.

Comment: Environment does not mean OS in my case. Environment means DEV, PRD, QA, etc.

Answer (score 1):

so you would have something like this:

```
application
-----------
application_id

server
-----------
server_id

application_instance
---------------------
application_id
instance_id
name <- name this one DEV, or PROD etc.
description <-  here describe the use of the DEV system
```

now say which one lives where...

```
server_instance
---------------
server_id
instance_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you require all three keys to be present in the joins, then you should go for the `AppServerEnvironments` solution. If the `Server/Application` pair does not require an `Enviroment` or the `Application/Environment` does not require a `Server`, then you'd best use the `ApplicationServer/ApplicationEnvironment` solution. This way, you can define composite primary keys on the tables without having `NULL` values.

Comment: In my case, an app env combo will always exists on a server. AppA's DEV environment will live on one or more servers. AppB's QA environment will live on one or more servers. AppA's DEV environment and AppB's QA environment may exists on the same server(s).